# Android: Is database of a system app removed with hard reset?

Tags: android, security, reset

I know that if you make some app system app by moving it to system path, it cannot be uninstalled normally (unless such tools are used) and neither it will go away after hard reset.

But does database of a system app gets removed/reset if hard reset is performed ?

Here is scenario: I install some app (may be anti-theft app). Now let's assume this app would store it's settings in database. If I hard-reset, will the database/settings of this app be removed after hard reset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard reset or "clear data" in app settings will remove all saved data.

Unless app save data in server side / Local path which does not deleted.